# Gauss' method to solve the following system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to use Gauss' method to solve the following system of equations and to describe
its solution set.  Can anyone help me getting started.
\begin{alignat*}{8}
x & + & y & + & z & - & w & = & 1\\
& & y & - &z & + & w & = & -1\\ 
3x & & & + & 6z & - & 6w & = & 6\\ 
& - & y & + & z & - & w & = & 1 
\end{alignat*}

Comment: To get started, divide both sides of the third equation by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The Gauss method is based on eliminating several variables in the system of linear equations by taking linear combinations. For example:

$1*(x+y+z-w)+1*(y-z+w)=x+2y=1*1+1*(-1)=0$ (added first equation to second).

$1*(3x+6z-6w)+(-6)*(-y+z-w)=3x+6y=1*6+(-6)*1=0$ (linear combination of third equation and 4th equation)

Now you have new linear equations $(A) x+2y=0, (B) 3x+6y=0$. Again you can take linear combinations like this: $3*(A)+(-1)*(B)=3*0+(-1)*0=0$. The linear System defined by (A) and (B) has no unique solution; therefore you can consider $x$ as a Parameter and you have: $y=- \frac{x}{2}$.